# Getting the EntityManager from an Embedded EJBContainer

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, ejb

How do I get the EntityManager from an instantiated EJBContainer (OpenEJB)?

I have tried using the `@PersistenceContext` annotation but it does not work.

Comment: JPA is required by the EJB 3.1 compliance test suite for embeddable EJB containers so it should be possible to make it work.  Can you show some code snippets?  Have you put the `@PersistenceContext` on an EJB class and not the unit test class?  Are you including a JPA provider on your classpath?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you are not running Unit tests in EJB container. So either you have to mock the `EntityManager` (for example with [Mockito)](http://mockito.org/) or I would suggest you using Arquillian which will allow to run your tests in reall container (which can be already running on some server or you can start it by yourself within the tests).

There is a nice tutorial on their Guides page on testing JPA so check it out :) [Testing Java Persistence](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/)

Comment: Are you sure?  The whole point of the embeddable EJB container is to allow this kind injection without needing to mock.  I know this scenario is required by the EJB 3.1 compliance test suite, and I know it works for WebSphere Application Server's embeddable EJB container.

Comment: Well, isn't it what I have written? Either mock or I am suggesting using Arquillian for running tests in real container so I don't really see the contradiction to your post.

Comment: OP's title says "from an embedded EJB Container", but your answer starts "you are not running Unit tests in EJB container".  OP *is* running in an EJB container, specifically the OpenEJB embedded EJB container, so it should work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your question is about a unit test but this works for me:

A "helper bean" in the (test) package:

```
@Stateless
public class EntityManagerProvider {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu-name")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

then look up that bean with the `EJBContainer` and get the `EntityManager`:

```
private EntityManager getEntityManager() throws NamingException {
    final EntityManagerProvider provider = (EntityManagerProvider)ejbContainer.getContext()
            .lookup("java:global/testproject/EntityManagerProvider");

    return provider.getEntityManager();
}
```